# OpenCV in multithreaded environment (OpenMP) causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, openmp, opencv3.0

I have OpenCV 3.0.0 installed. My code is multithreaded using OpenMP.

Each thread accesses the same opencv function ("convertTo").

This causes a segmentation fault.

The error does not occurr

1. if I print a simple statement using std::cout at the beginning of each thread or
2. if I use only a single thread.

Can anyone help, what the reason might be?

Comment: Is the Mat object shared between threads?

Comment: No, the "convertTo" works on different matrices

Comment: Can you show some code so it will be easier to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm working on it, sorry for the delay, but extracting it from a large project takes some time

Comment: Your std::cout call might be synchronizing your threads, since only one thread can write to std::out at a time.  

I am curious though, do you threads modify any global data?  Did you check with clang's static analyzer for any bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Many functions and data openCV use the same memory addresses for different variables, for example if you have a matrix Mat A and you do Mat B = A, data matrix B are stored in the same pociciones memory A, now when you use OpenMP must make sure that when you write to a memory location, just do it from a single thread, otherwise you will get an error at runtime.

Now when you use a single thread there is no problem, since it is only one thread which writes or reads a pocicion memory.

On the other hand when you use functions to print screen as printf () or std :: cout, there is the possibility that the threads are delayed, that is, that while a thread prints, another thread writes to the memory locations, by thus the possibility of an error at runtime decline, but that does not mean that in the future do not exist.

The solution when you use OpenMP in a loop to protect write in the same memory locations from different threads is:`

```
 #pragma omp critical
{
    //code only be written from a thread
}
```